# Convert PDF to a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

How to convert a PDF to a Google Sheet which I deleted and is in my MacBook Air trash to a functional Sheet & save into Google Drive where I can continue to use it as a fully functional Sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the PDF of the sheet you could try to upload the file to your Google Drive by going to [drive.google.com](https://drive.google.com) and clicking the "New" button in the top left corner of your screen. The tap "File Upload" and upload the PDF to your Drive.

[image]

Next, highlight the whole PDF that should now be in your Drive, open a new Google Sheet, and paste the whole thing there. It should be fully functional now, with everything from the PDF now in the Sheet.